# Bizarre spacing with 4 $\star$s

Tags: math-mode, spacing

The spacing between the 3rd and 4th stars is non-existent. Anyone know what's up?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\star\star\star\star \\
\star\star\star\,\star \\
\star\star\star\star\star
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\star` is a `\mathbin` so looking for something to each side to give even spacing.  Cf. just `\star\star`.  Add `{}` after the final `\star` to get uniform wide spacing back.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the term, and googling didn't help elucidate anything either. What does being a mathbin have to do with 4 consecutive occurrences and the use of {}?

Comment: I am not sure, if you are asking about *why* does this happen, or *how to deal* with it. But you can wrap every `\star` into braces: `{\star}`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Math symbols have different classifications and `\star` like `-` is a classed as binary operator. TeX assigns different space between symbols of each type, but also binary operators if not appearing in "infix" position, essentially revert to being an ordinary operator `\mathord` rather than `\mathbin`).

The motivation here can be seen better with `-`

[image]

`1-2` the `-` is spaced as an infix operator but when not used between two symbols it reverts to closer spacing for `-2`.

When you have one or two `-` they are ordinary symbols with no space, but if you have three then the middle one acquires its natural mathbin spacing. Then the fourth, being between the third (which is a mathord) and the end of the math list, is again mathord so gets no space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

[$1-2$]

[$-2$]

[$-$]

[$--$]

[$---$]

[$----$]

[${}----{}$]

[${-}{-}{-}{-}$]

\end{document}
```

The final two lines show  two ways of getting even space, with `\mathbin` or  `\mathord` spacing.

Comment: +1 for the ability  of turn  TeX mysteries as plain as the nose in your face.

Comment: It was your the answer :-) +1.