# Three stars or asterisks

Tags: math-mode

I noticed that `$***$` produces spaces between the stars while `$**$` does not.
Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: @egreg Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: Yes, it is discussed somewhere: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372326/121799. @azetina Too bad, you are calling for egreg and get David instead. ;-)

Comment: Oh... so $***$ is "star times star" thanks @marmot

Comment: @marmot my apologies :)

Comment: I'd say not "star times star" but "star convoluted with star".

Comment: @SergeiGolovan actually I was just reading a paper where the main function constructed is called $*$ (but it is never convoluted with itself)

Comment: @marmot some people just get lucky