# Label several equations with symbols without leaving a blank space

Tags: math-mode, equations, symbols, labels

So I am labeling three equations with symbols, each one in a different line. The problem is that when I do this, a huge amont of blank space is left between equations, and I don't like it. Can someone help me fix this? I am open to different ideas like sticking the equations in an array or something like that, but it is important that each one has its own label.

Here is my code:

```
\[c_1a_1=r_{12}a_2+r_{13}a_3 \label{eq:star1}\tag{$\star$}\] 
\[c_2a_2=r_{21}a_1+r_{23}a_3 \label{eq:star2}\tag{$\star\star$}\]
\[c_3a_3=r_{31}a_1+r_{32}a_2 \label{eq:star2}\tag{$\star\star\star$}\]
```

This is how it looks:
[image]
Also, the stars in the second equation are very close and in the third one they are rather separated. How can I fix this?

Comment: nevr use consecuive display mah enviornments, use a multline display, you must have amsmath loaded as you use `\tag` so use \begin[align}` here (and `&=`  to align on =)

Comment: for the * use `{*}` `{*}{*}` and `{*}{*}{*}`  (we have a question about that somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle , that solves all my problems

Comment: Mostly same question as [math mode - Bizarre spacing with 4 $\star$s - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372326/bizarre-spacing-with-4-stars). -- except that `text` should be used here, mostly.

Answer (score 2):

You first of all should not have consecutive `\[...\]`. Since tags are in text mode, use text.

Unfortunately, `\textstar` is currently not defined, but if it ever will be, the definition with `\providecommand` will be ignored and result in the same output.

(Note: `twocolumn` is used just to make a smaller picture.)

```
\documentclass[leqno,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\providecommand{\textstar}{\ensuremath{\star}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
c_1a_1 &= r_{12}a_2+r_{13}a_3 \label{eq:star1} \tag{\textstar} \\
c_2a_2 &= r_{21}a_1+r_{23}a_3 \label{eq:star2} \tag{\textstar\textstar} \\
c_3a_3 &= r_{31}a_1+r_{32}a_2 \label{eq:star3} \tag{\textstar\textstar\textstar}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the problem with `$\star\star\star$`? `\star` is an operation symbol, but if it's used “out of context” it will behave as an ordinary symbol. So, the first `\star` is ordinary, the last one is ordinary, but the middle one retains its operation symbol nature, so TeX adds spaces.