# Nested align without extra spacing

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I am trying to align the + symbols, while also aligning the = symbols, as such

[image]

As you can see, I managed to align at the ='s but not the +'s, how can I do that? This is the code I used (using quad to kind of align them):

```
                x &= a + b (ert)\\
            &\quad\quad + c(ert)\\
            &= abc
```

When I try something like this:

```
            x &= a &&+ b (ert)\\
            & &&+ c(ert)\\
            &= abc
```

I get this:
[image]

I also tried alignat, and split inside align, but nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `alignat` but as you want the wrapped summation to overlap the abc on the last row, a nested `aligned` is better

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

alignat
\begin{alignat}{-1}
    x &= a &&+ b (ert)\\
      &    &&+ c(ert)\nonumber\\
      &= abc  
\end{alignat}

aligned
\begin{align}
    x &=\begin{aligned}[t]
         a &+ b (ert)\\
           &+ c(ert)
         \end{aligned}\\
      &= abc  
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `-1` alignment points... :-o

Comment: @Werner documented feature means "as many as neeeded" actually `align` is defined to use -1 in that slot rather than have a user argument

Comment: Riiight. Found it in the [implementation notes](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf) (under section **17.4 Simple aligning environments**; **`\start@aligned`**).

Comment: Thanks, that second option worked perfectly, exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Can you tell me, what the [t] option is for?

Comment: @Tom `t` = **top**, try it without and you will see

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple with `alignat` and the `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
     x &= a &&+ b (ert)\\
                & &&+ c(ert)\\
                &=\mathrlap{abc}
    \end{alignat*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `a` outside the `\mathrlap`? Just to be complicated? 

Comment: @egreg: Not quite:  I just thought that probably the `$a$ ` s would not be well aligned and I didn't have time to test. This morning, I have more time and I could. You're right: there's no difference, and I'll fix it within seconds. Thank you for your comment! :o)

Comment: What does the `\mathrlap` do here? In my real code I have a bunch more lines, would I need that for all following lines then?

Comment: @Tom; it places in math mode an expression and makes latex believe it has  0 width, so that it adds no horizontal space between the two alignment points. There exists also  `\mathlap`, which is like the basic `\llap`, but in math mode. To make it fully clear , compare with  the spacing you obtain without this command.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can probably use a `\phantom` here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
x & = a + b (ert)\\
  & \phantom{{} = a} + c (ert)\\
  & = abc
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(In case you wonder why the `{}` are needed: The equals sign is a binary operator which, if it does not have a symbol before and after it, changes its spacing bahavior. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372329/47927) about more on this.)